# JFreeChart - проблема с отрисовкой графиков

Tags: java, excel, javafx, swing, графика

Мне нужно с помощью **JFreeChart** нарисовать график как в Excel, но я сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой:
[image: Exel graphic]
[image: Java graphic]

Как видите, координаты и фигуры полностью совпадают, но в java "неправильная для меня" прорисовка графика, какие методы использовать, чтобы график прорисовывался как в Excel?

Мой java код:

```java
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyGraph {
    private static double A=20, R0=-40;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("my graphic");

        for (double fi = 0,step = 0.05; fi < 2*Math.PI; fi+=step) addCoordinate(series,fi);

        XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory
                .createXYLineChart("my graphic 14", "x", "y",
                        xyDataset,
                        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                        true, true, true);
        JFrame frame =
                new JFrame("MinimalStaticChart");
        frame.getContentPane()
                .add(new ChartPanel(chart));
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private static void addCoordinate(XYSeries series,double fi){
        double ro = Math.cos(fi)-0.5;
        series.add(ro*Math.cos(fi),ro*Math.sin(fi));
        System.out.printf("fi = %f   ro = %f   x = %f   y = %f\n", fi , ro, ro*Math.cos(fi), ro*Math.sin(fi));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, в принципе логично - у вас не тот тип графика. У вас `XYLineRenderer` отрисовывает последовательно для каждого x соответствующее значение y, т.е. он как бы сортирует массив x и строит. Вам лучше сменить тип графиков или покопаться в настройках, чтобы он строил график по заданному вами массиву точек.

Answer (score 3):

Нашел решение:
Нужно сменить

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("my graphic");
```

на

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("my graphic", false);
```

Comment: у вас просто стоит сортировка, которая поумолчанию включена, выключить можно как в самом графике так и как в ответе